# Preparing insert statement for multiple columns

Tags: php, sql, prepared-statement

I'm trying to insert first name, last name, email and password into my db, but of course I want to prepare the statement first. I searched around google and stack, but couldn't find anything about the syntax for inserting multiple columns, only one. What do I use in place of ? of prepare statement and bind_param().

Here is my code:

```
if(!($sql = $link->prepare("INSERT INTO users(fname, lname, email, password) VALUE(fname=?, lname=?, email=?, password=?))){
    echo "Prepare failed: (" . $link->errno . ") " . $link->error;
}

$sql->bind_param('?', $fname);
$sql->bind_param('?', $lname);
$sql->bind_param('?', $email);
$sql->bind_param('?', $hashpass);
$sql->execute();
```

EDIT: Is it even possible? Do I have to do each separately?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using MySQLi? It looks like you are. If so, you only need to call `bind_param` once and in the `VALUES` part of the SQL just put comma separated question marks to represent each column:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO users(fname, lname, email, password) VALUE(?, ?, ?, ?)";

if( !$sql = $link->prepare($query) ) {
    echo "Prepare failed: (" . $link->errno . ") " . $link->error;
}

$sql->bind_param("ssss", $fname, $lname, $email, $hashpass);
$sql->execute();
```

See the [mysqli `bind_param` documentation](http://jp.php.net//manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) for more information.

P.S. I cleaned up the code a little and put the SQL in a variable to make it cleaner.